# SheepIt: find id of each control and bind dropdownlist with database using asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application where i am using SheepIt plugin to dynamically generate controls like textboxes and dropdownlist.I want to bind textboxes with jquery-ui-calender and I want to bind dropdownlist with the database items. My code is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sheepItPlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var sheepItForm = {};

    $(document).ready(function () {

        sheepItForm = $('#sheepItForm').sheepIt({
            separator: '',
            allowRemoveLast: true,
            allowRemoveCurrent: true,
            allowRemoveAll: true,
            allowAdd: true,
            allowAddN: true,
            maxFormsCount: 10,
            minFormsCount: 0,
            iniFormsCount: 0,

            afterAdd: function (source, newForm) {

                $(".from").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                        $(".to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                });

                $(".to").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                        $(".from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "SheepingExample.aspx/BindDatatoDropdown",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                            $("#sheepItForm_#index#_ddlRoom").append($("<option></option>").val(value.ID).html(value.Name));
                        });
                    }
                });

            }

        });

    });
</script>
<style>
    a {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #00F;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #sheepItForm_controls div, #sheepItForm_controls div input {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #executeLink {
        clear: both;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

 <!-- sheepIt Form -->
<div id="sheepItForm">

    <!-- Form template-->
    <div id="sheepItForm_template">
        <label for="sheepItForm_#index#_phone">Booking Details <span id="sheepItForm_label"></span></label>
        <input id="sheepItForm_#index#_phone" name="person[phones][#index#][phone]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="10" style="display: none;" />
        <select id="sheepItForm_#index#_ddlRoom" name="person[phones][#index#][ddlRoom]" class="sel"></select>
        <input id="sheepItForm_#index#_from" class="from" placeholder="Enter From Date" name="person[phones][#index#][from]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="10" />
        <input id="sheepItForm_#index#_to" class="to" placeholder="Enter to Date" name="person[phones][#index#][to]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="10" />
        <a id="sheepItForm_remove_current">
            <img class="delete" src="images/cross.png" width="16" height="16" border="0">
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /Form template-->

    <!-- No forms template -->
    <div id="sheepItForm_noforms_template">No phones</div>
    <!-- /No forms template-->

    <!-- Controls -->
    <div id="sheepItForm_controls">
        <div id="sheepItForm_add"><a><span>Add phone</span></a></div>
        <div id="sheepItForm_remove_last"><a><span>Remove</span></a></div>
        <div id="sheepItForm_remove_all"><a><span>Remove all</span></a></div>
        <div id="sheepItForm_add_n">
            <input id="sheepItForm_add_n_input" type="text" size="4" />
            <div id="sheepItForm_add_n_button"><a><span>Add</span></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Controls -->


</div>
<!-- /sheepIt Form -->


</body>
</html>
```

and My webservice to bind dropdownlist database-items is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static RoomType[] BindDatatoDropdown()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    List<RoomType> details = new List<RoomType>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Raju;Integrated Security=true"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Name FROM RoomType_Master", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            RoomType room = new RoomType();
            room.ID = 0;
            room.Name = "select";
            details.Add(room);
            foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
            {
                RoomType country = new RoomType();
                country.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["ID"].ToString());
                country.Name = dtrow["Name"].ToString();
                details.Add(country);
            }
        }
    }
    return details.ToArray();
}
```

but when i try to bind dropdownlist with its id then is not getting bind. Also it not giving any error. please help me someone.

Comment: When the page renders, can you post some sample markup of that as well?  Curious how the HTML looks when all of this runs...

Comment: There's kind of a lot of code here.  Where does it fail?  When you debug this, at what point does it deviate from expected behavior?  Is the AJAX call successfully receiving the data you expect?  Is that data being handled as you expect?  Debug this, find where the problem becomes evident.  Don't just treat the whole thing as a black box and say "it doesn't work."

Comment: yes the ajax request is called and the control goes to webmethod but the dropdownlist is not getting bind.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the `$(document).ready()` function expects all the elements to be loaded in the DOM. Any dynamically loaded elements will be ignored and that's why it won't bind; it can't find the element on the page. There are alternate methods in jQuery (see docs) or you can re-register the scripts.

If using MVC razor:

```
@if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()){
    <script>...</script>
}
```

If using WebForms, use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

In jQuery, you can use event delegation like so:

```
$('<selector>').on('click', '#target', function(){…});
```